# Align text to image - React Native

Tags: css, image, react-native

I am trying to align the social icon texts under each image like so:

[image: Social Icons]

However, I am getting these results:

[image]

I placed each row as a separate view

```
<View style={styles.socialIcons}>
    <Image source={require("social/facebook-icon.png")} />
    <Image source={require("social/twitter-icon.png")} />
    <Image source={require("social/mail-icon.png")} />
    <Image source={require("social/message-icon.png")} />
</View>
<View style={styles.socialIconsText}>
    <Text style={styles.socialIconText}>Facebook</Text>
    <Text style={styles.socialIconText}>Twitter</Text>
    <Text style={styles.socialIconText}>Email</Text>
    <Text style={styles.socialIconText}>Message</Text>
</View>
```

followed by their styles:

```
socialIcons: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 40,
    paddingRight: 40,
},
socialIconsText: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 40,
    paddingRight: 40,
},
```

I think what I should be doing instead is to place the text inside the image tags but, when I do that the images height cuts off any text under it. Is there a way to get the image heights and increase the height in the styles?

Or is there a better way to align the text underneath the images?

Answer (score 0):

i think the padding interferes with the text.

also try to make every image and text element 25% in width + box-sizing: border-box; and center text.

Answer (score 0):

İnstead of seperating image and text of facebook, twitter ... Covering them in a special wiew is better idea. In this way you will have much more control on your views and you can make a dynamic implementation.

```
<View style = {{flex:1}}>
 <View style={{height:80, width:80}}> 
  <Image style ={{flex:1}}>
   ... 
  </Image>
  <Text style={{flex:1}}>
  </Text>
 </View> 
 .
 .
 .
</View>
```

Creating a function for returning special views will save you from repeating codes.

getSpecView(uri,text)//use this params to specify your images and texts
{
  return(
    
       ... 
      
      
      
      
  );
}
And now you just have to do is calling this function

```
 <View style = {{flex:1}}>
     getSpecView(*faceuri, *facetext)
     getSpecView(*twitter, *twittertext)
     .
     .
    </View>
```

You can even get rid of calling this function several times for every couple by creating an Json array and calling map function

```
couples = [{ name:'facebook', uri:'faceuri'  }, { name:'twitter', uri:'twitter uri'}]
```

and now you just have a three lines of codes + a function and a json array.

```
      <View style = {{flex:1}}>
        couples.map(this.getSpecView(name,uri))// not sure about syntax
        </View>
```

If you have trouble with images you can use resizeModes
resizeMode PropTypes.oneOf(['cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center']) 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html